# How to create the bootstrap rows and columns dynamically in ng for loop

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-grid

I have the data(number of maps)coming  from the backend, So I need to place the maps on the page.
But the maps has to place even and odd condition
**(i.e if the length of the maps are one it has to show the map on entire page. if it is two it has to place the two maps in a row if it is three it has to show two maps in one row and one map in another row with entire width)**

**dashboard.component.html**

```
<div class="col-sm-5"  *ngFor="let map of sensors; let i = index" >
   <span *ngIf = "sensors.length % 2 == 1 && i < sensors.length - 1">
      <div id="map{{i}}" style="height: 300px;border: 1px solid gray;">
      </div>
   </span>
   <span *ngIf = "sensors.length % 2 == 0">
      <div id="map{{i}}" style="height: 300px;border: 1px solid gray;">
      </div>
   </span>
</div>
<span *ngIf = "sensors.length % 2 == 1">
   <div class="col-sm-8">
      <div id="map{{sensors.length - 1}}"  style="height: 300px;border: 1px solid gray;">
      </div>
   </div>
</span>
```

For the above code two maps are loading but third map is not loading.

I have tried multiple ways but not able to find the solution, can anyone help me regarding this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is most likely a better way, but first thing that came to mind, not very dynamic, hope it helps, assuming `Bootstrap 4`:

- one item: the col will be full width
- two items: the cols will be even width on one row
- three items: first 2 will be even width on one row, third will be forced on second row full width

given:

```
sensors = [
    'https://via.placeholder.com/150',
    'https://via.placeholder.com/150',
    'https://via.placeholder.com/150'
]
```

template:

```
<div class="row">
    <div *ngFor="let map of sensors; let i = index" class="col p-2" [ngClass]="{ 'col-12' : sensors.length==3&& i==2}">
        <img [src]="map" width="100%">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Thibs, I have tested your code but three maps are coming with entire width ,but I want two maps in one row, third map in another row with entire width and so on.. Can you please edit the above code for my requirement.

Comment: Thanks @ Thibs, Can you please help me for one more requirement, that is if I select two means which has to come left and right ,if I select third one ,then It is coming as first row one half  and second row second half.  But I want is irrespective of order it has to come first entire width and then left and right.